# How to create Java .pptx file upload functionality?

Tags: java, powerpoint

multiReq.getFilesystemName return null name in .pptx case but work well in all other extension.

```
ResourceBundle res = ResourceBundle.getBundle("Application");
String servername = request.getRequestURI();
servername = servername.substring(0, servername.lastIndexOf("/"));
                if (servername.indexOf("/servlet") > 0)
                    servername = servername.substring(0, servername.indexOf("servlet"));
                attach.append(res.getString("smileswrk"));
                attach.append("/attachments");
                attach.append(request.getRequestURI().substring(0, index_u));
                attach.append("/");
                attach.append("performance");
                attach.append("/");
File dir = new File(attach.toString());
                if (!dir.isDirectory())
                    dir.mkdirs();
    MultipartRequest multiReq = new MultipartRequest(request, attach.toString(), 100 * 1024 * 1024);
strfile = multiReq.getFilesystemName("goaluploadingFile");
```

I am creating directory so that user can download it later from view after uploading it for that file need to be stored in server directory and this code is not working in .pptx because `MultipartRequest.getFilesystemName` method return null in case of `.pptx` file but in other extension case it gives uploaded file name like for instance `abc.txt`.

Comment: I think it is rather unclear what you are asking - what problem are you having in particular?

Comment: Why would you be creating a directory when *uploading*? And how can the file extension possibly affect the working of this code? What is the question here?

Comment: @EJP i am creating directory so that user can download it later from view after uploading it for that file need to be stored in server direcotry and this code is not working in .pptx because MultipartRequest.getFilesystemName method return null in case of ,pptx file but in other extension case it gives uploaded file name like for instance abc.txt i think this answer might be able to change your negative view about my question or you will come forward to help a beginner and even if you didn't i still want to thank for your time :)

Comment: @halfer i will request you to read my reply i gave to mr. EJP

Comment: So you are uploading a file so you can download it again? Why? And why not create the directory at download time when it is needed, instead of at upload time when it isn't? And what makes you think that creating a file on the client will magically provide you with a directory on the server? This is not making any sense.